# OnClickListener with ImageButton

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-imagebutton

I want to create a little app which shows several pictures and if you click on of it a toast pops and says the name. I cant really figure out why it crashes immediately. LogCat says something like Nullpointerexpection?! Thank you for very much in advance for your help.

```
  package com.example.housesgot;
  import android.os.Bundle;
  import android.annotation.SuppressLint;
  import android.app.Activity;
  import android.view.View;
  import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
  import android.widget.ImageButton;
  import android.widget.Toast;

  @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
  public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener 
  {

      ImageButton  imageButton1,imageButton2,imageButton3,imageButton4,imageButton5,imageButton6;
      @Override
      protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) 
      {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
            imageButton1=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.house_baratheon);
            imageButton2=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.house_frey);
            imageButton3=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.house_greyjoy);
            imageButton4=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.house_lannister);
            imageButton5=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.house_stark);
            imageButton6=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.drawable.house_targaryen);
            imageButton1.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageButton2.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageButton3.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageButton4.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageButton5.setOnClickListener(this);
            imageButton6.setOnClickListener(this);
      }


    @SuppressLint("ShowToast")
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) 
    {
        if(v==imageButton1){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.baratheon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}
        if(v==imageButton2){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.frey, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}
        if(v==imageButton3){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.greyjoy, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}
        if(v==imageButton4){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.lannister, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}
        if(v==imageButton5){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.stark, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}
        if(v==imageButton6){
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.targaryen, Toast.LENGTH_LONG);}

     }
}
```

Comment: it might be that your variable never get assigned when you are trying to do `findViewById`, reason for that could be because it hasn't finished setting up the xml layout

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.drawable.house_baretheon);`

Notice how the method is called `findViewById`, so you should ACTUALLY be supplying it the ID that you registered to the image button

You have to first set the content view of your activity

`setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);`

This will set the screen, and put all those buttons on there, AFTER you have made this call you need to grab a reference to all the imagebuttons.

`layout/activity_main.xml` should have an imagebutton like this for all the items

```
<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/button_house_baretheon"
    android:src="@drawable/house_baretheon"
    ... />
```

Then grab the reference by calling

`imageButton1 = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.button_house_baretheon)`

The rest of your code is fine.

**Edit**

Oh wait one more thing, you need to call show() after the `makeText()` method call, so like this

Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, R.string.baratheon, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

Comment: So I have changed both things as you said.. the one with the id and the thing with the strings. Now the layout looks fine but nothing happens if i click on one of the pictures.I honestly dont know how to post logcat accurately...

Answer (score 0):

Since you've posted no logcat, I can't correct your code, but I can give you a working example:

```
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.belfast_map);


      ImageButton ib1,ib2,ib3,ib4,ib5;

       //change your image ID's here
       ib1= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.go_to_lagan_screen);
       ib2= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.go_to_city);
       ib3= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.go_to_university);
       ib4= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.go_to_icon_screen);
       ib5= (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.map_to_home_screen);


       ib1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
       {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
             //change the action here, a toast in your example
             Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, MainActivity.this.getResources().getString(R.string.my_resource_string), Toast.LENGTH_LONG);

          }
       } );

       ib2.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener()
       {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
             Intent intent1= new Intent (MapScreen.this, CityCentre.class);
             startActivity(intent1);
             //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
          }
       }));
       ib3.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener()
       {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
             Intent intent2= new Intent (MapScreen.this, UniversityArea.class);
             startActivity(intent2);
             //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
          }
       }));
       ib4.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener()
       {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
             Intent intent3= new Intent (MapScreen.this, TheIcons.class);
             startActivity(intent3);

             //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
          }
       }));
       ib5.setOnClickListener((new View.OnClickListener()
       {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v)
          {
             Intent intent4= new Intent (MapScreen.this, MyActivity.class);
             startActivity(intent4);
             //To change body of implemented methods use File | Settings | File Templates.
          }
       }));
    }
```

Comment: actually, the `makeText()` method from the `Toast` class accepts String id's

Comment: @user3533210 You welcome! If the answer helps you please press the green mark below the up/down vote button. Thanks!